# Sidecaption and capion text

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, koma-script, sidenotes

I am using koma script with the sidenotes package.

Can I redefine `\sidecaption` to get syntax `\ caption [Text in list of figures] {Text next to the figure}`

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{sidenotes}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[htb]
        \sidecaption[][-2\baselineskip]{Text next to image 1}%Missing lof description
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{figure}
    
\begin{figure}[htb]
        \caption[Text in listoffigures]{Text next to image 2}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The choice of the optional arguments in `\sidecaption` is not the best possible. Probably a better choice for the syntax would be

```
\sidecaption[<list entry>]{<caption>}[<offset>]
```

but the package author didn't thought so.

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \sidecaption[Text next to image 1][-2\baselineskip]{Text next to image 1}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
```

You might want to use a different command with the better syntax.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{sidenotes}

\NewDocumentCommand{\SideCaption}{sO{#3}mo}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {% \sidecaption*
    \IfNoValueTF{#4}{\sidecaption*{#3}}{\sidecaption*[#4]{#3}}%
   }
   {% \sidecaption
    \IfNoValueTF{#4}{\sidecaption[#2]{#3}}{\sidecaption[#2][#4]{#3}}%
   }%
}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[htb]

\SideCaption{Text next to image 1}[-2\baselineskip]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}

\end{figure}
    
\begin{figure}[htb]

\SideCaption[Lof text]{Text next to image 2}[-2\baselineskip]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}

\end{figure}
    
\begin{figure}[htb]

\caption[Text in listoffigures]{Text next to image 3}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]